# I want to do several functions on PHP/MySQL but is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a program where you can upload automaticly a .CVS file to my database. To do this I use a lot of functions on php (For create new tables and separate the file into a smaller tables)

So my HTML code is like this:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<!-- Functions --> 
<?php CreateTable1(); ?>
<?php CreateTable1(); ?>
<?php CreateTable1(); ?>
<?php ... ?>
</div>
```

And my functions are like this:

```
function CreateTable() {
    // Create connection
    $conn = Conectar();
    // Modificar acentos y Ñ
    $acentos = $conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE ...";
    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
        echo "<p>Tabla truncate</p>";
    else 
        echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
    $sql = "...";
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         ...
        }   
    }
    else 
        echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
    $conn->close();
}
```

When I run the program, only the first 2 functions work! What can i do to solve it?

Comment: If I try the functions separate they works

Comment: It is not very clear to me what the problem is and how it is related to uploading csv files, but are you perhaps hitting php's default maximum script time of 30 seconds?

Comment: There is also the possibility that the query isn't finished when it says it is. Ran into this a while back: query still executing in mysql process list and in php it was finished.

Comment: As @Alex says trace your code by adding some echos between the lines

Comment: Thanks @jeroen! now it's working